# Continuous hour range in SQL - which data type to use?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

This is probably a very basic question but I'm new to SQL and couldn't find an appropriate answer. I'm currently working with the following data, in hrs:mins:seconds

```
Machine Running Time
22:09:40
19:39:12
18:17:59
17:32:23
17:46:50
42:19:38
33:11:36
18:57:01
20:47:40
19:51:24
```

As you can see it's a continuous number of hours, not the 24 hour time system. In order to manipulate it (find the average time length), what data type should I set the column to? I've tried various types of TIME etc but to no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: If those values are durations, then you should use an `interval`

Comment: Fastest response ever! Very new to all of this so I wasn't aware I could do that. Thank you for the help.